# Web Plugin Rule "InlineStyleCheck" creates False Positives on JSP custom tags

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube [Web Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Plugin) created a lot of False Positives, because of the use of the JSP custom tags with "style" name.

[image: Example file with issues]

Environment:

- SonarQube 5.1
- SonarQube [Web Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Plugin) 2.3
- Jenkins 1.611
- Sonar Runner 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the rule. It marks all elements which local name is equal to `style`. Authors of the SonarQube [Web Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Web+Plugin) have created an issue: [SONARWEB-30](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARWEB-30). It will be fixed in 2.4 version.